# Problem understanding OALD entry definition

Tags: meaning

> League: a group of sports teams who all play each other to earn points and find which team is best. 
>   major league baseball. 
>      **United were league champions last season.** 
>      If we look at the league table we can see Bolton **are** bottom with 21 points.

The above paragraph is Oxford Dictionary's definition for *league*. The first part in bold doesn't make sense to me. It is not clear whether it says champions were united last season? Or that United club was (why *were* is used if so?) champion of the league last season.
Also, why is *Bolton* written with *are* rather than *is*?

Comment: "United" is the team and it's not uncommon to use the plural when you're talking about a team because it is a group of people.... same thing for the plural "are" after Bolton... which is another team.

Comment: @Catija, is it why champion is also plural?

Comment: To agree with "were"... if it said "United was league" it would continue "champion"... It might help to imagine that the sentence actually says "The **players** on the Manchester United team **were** league **champions** last season.

Comment: This was probably the toughest English sentence I have seen in my life :)

Comment: I wonder which United they were. I know quite a few teams with *United* in their names: Manchester United, West Ham United, Newcastle United, and Leeds United. :-)

Comment: But please note that this use of "are" with a team is much more common in British English than American English. In the daily sports pages of a US newspaper, no American reporter is going to use "are" to refer to a single team.

Answer (score 1):

Not so acquainted with sports played in the western world, but I can make you understand taking cricket as an example.

In cricket, we often see the comparison of two teams after certain [overs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Over_%28cricket%29)

The information goes this way:

> After 23 overs:
>
> India ***were*** 100/3 
>  Australia ***are*** 98/2

The single digit number talks about [wickets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wicket). '

As rightly said in comments, when we consider 'team',  we consider *players* actually. And, that's the reason, we see team name (in Cricket, even nation's name) is described as plural proper nouns.

I cannot get you the screenshots because it happens on the TV, live!

However, I found such entry in [Hindustan Times](http://www.hindustantimes.com/cricket-world-cup-2015/worldcup2015-topstories/10-blockbusters-between-india-and-australia-so-far-11th-coming-up-on-march-26/article1-1328727.aspx), a reputed daily here.

> ***India were*** bowled out for 158 in 37.5 overs. Kapil top scored with 40 off 27 balls. Ken MacLeay (6/39) wrecked India’s chase.

On the same page...

> ***Australia were*** dismissed for 129 in 38.2 overs. The medium pace of Roger Binny (4/29 in 8 overs) and Madan Lal (4/20 in 8.2 overs) proved too hot to handle.